# Enter BIOS on VM with Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, bios

I have a virtual machine running ubuntu 18. I need to access BIOS in order to turn on EIST. I have already enabled EFI on the VM settings. When pressing F2 when booting, BIOS settings should appear. But for me, this appears as below.

What should I do to access BIOS and turn on EIST?

Edit: I'm using Virtual Box

[image]

Comment: Which virtualization product?

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox

Comment: What you are getting may really be the atrophied BIOS that is used by VirtualBox. But try to give yourself more time by setting the length of time (in milliseconds) that the boot splash screen is shown to 10 seconds using the command `VBoxManage modifyvm VMNAME --bioslogodisplaytime 10000`.

Comment: A virtual machine cannot have a setting for Enhanced Intel SpeedStep Technology. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to set the CPU speed by following these steps: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/comment/1716807/how-to-change-frequency-on-linux-pub.txt

Comment: I have a Macbook Pro

Comment: And my project involves using a multi core system and changing the frequency of the cores. I've tried simulators but they don't do what I what, so I was hoping I could try doing that on my machine

Comment: You’ll have to do that on a real machine, without virtualization software.

Comment: Thank you! If I partition my mac for linux, do you think I'll be able to do this? Or do you think (because of the mac hardware) I won't be able to change the frequency of the cores?